# Swift: How to add Dictionary format in forHTTPHeaderField in GET request

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

In GET request, I am trying to add header.

```
request.setValue(value: String?, forHTTPHeaderField: "SessionInfo")
```

But, `SessionInfo` value is in `[String : Any]`

**Attempt 1:**

```
func SO_Function() {

    let service_url = WebService.sharedManager().serviceURL
    let getMenuURL = service_url + "/MyPage/FileDownload.ashx"

    var convertedString = ""

    do {
        let data1 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: WebService.sharedManager().mobInfoDict, options: [])
        convertedString = String(data: data1, encoding: .utf8)!
        print("\n\nconvertedJSONtoData  ", convertedString)

    } catch {
        print("\n\nCAtcLL___Err   ",error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let url = NSURL(string: getMenuURL)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    //Below line, If I can able to add [String:Any] then I will get 
    proper Image as output.

    request.setValue(convertedString, forHTTPHeaderField: "SessionInfo")
    request.setValue("67a2a6fb1d13450a", forHTTPHeaderField: "Flowid")
    request.setValue("d29566ac42de4e99", forHTTPHeaderField: "Fileid")
    request.setValue("LMS_LEAVEREQUEST", forHTTPHeaderField: "Form")

    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let mData = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let img = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.attachmentImgVw.image = img
            }

        }else{
            print("\n\nError: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }
    mData.resume()
}
```

**Output**

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

**Error ScreenShot 1:**

[image]

**Postman Screenshot**

In postman, I am giving `SessionInfo` value as in `Dictionary` format. Working fine.

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: `print("\n\nCAtcLL___Err   ",error.localizedDescription)` That's the line that prints the output? What's `WebService.sharedManager().mobInfoDict`?

Comment: yes,  this line prints output.  This is, WebService.sharedManager().mobInfoDict , [String:Any], {"CompnayID" : "Qa55", "Token" : "123", "number" : "916"}

Comment: What's the content of `WebService.sharedManager().mobInfoDict`? It's not JSON valid apparently. Once you made if JSON valid (ie, only String, Number, Null, Dict & Array).

Comment: WebService.sharedManager().mobInfoDict =  {"CompnayID" : "Qa55", "Token" : 123, "number" : 916, "Language" : "en-CA"}

Comment: The same JSON format, I have given in POSTMAN, that's working fine.

Comment: Is that a String? Because that's not a valid "Swift Dict declaration"? Is that a String? That's unclear, that's not valid Swift Code. How did you set it? Could you print it?

Comment: I will give u, but only one doubt is thr, How to add Dictionary in forHTTPHeaderField ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194891/discussion-between-mcdonal-11-and-larme).

Comment: By converting it into a JSON String apparently. But your error says that's it's can't be transformed into JSON. So there is an issue there.

Comment: @Larme , Hope, this may be an issue?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593307/swift-unable-to-add-prettyprinted-format-string-to-forhttpheaderfield