# Swift: Unable to add .prettyPrinted format String to forHTTPHeaderField

Tags: swift, nsmutableurlrequest, nshttpurlresponse

By continuing [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582434/swift-how-to-add-dictionary-format-in-forhttpheaderfield-in-get-request) ,

I am trying to convert `[String : Any]` into `String` and then passing that `String` into `forHTTPHeaderField`

**Attempt 1:** Without Pretty

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()

if let json = try? encoder.encode(jsonDict) {
   convertedString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!
}

print("JsonStringFormat     ", convertedString )

let url = NSURL(string: getMenuURL)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.setValue(convertedString, forHTTPHeaderField: "SessionInfo")

print("\nHEADer__reQQ__    ", request.allHTTPHeaderFields)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
JsonStringFormat      {"Token":"96FFC5B994514B3D","UICulture":"en-CA ","LanguageCode":"ENG","CompanyID":"QAP","IMEINo":"1jzBG3TSrMzj\/tKihlEv8g=="}
HEADer__reQQ__     ["SessionInfo": "{\"Token\":\"96FFC5B994514B3D\",\"LanguageCode\":\"ENG\",\"UICulture\":\"en-CA \",\"CompanyID\":\"QAP\",\"IMEINo\":\"1jzBG3TSrMzj\\/tKihlEv8g==\"}"]
```

**Attempt 2:** With .pretty printed

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()

// ADDING PRETTY FORMAT
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

if let json = try? encoder.encode(jsonDict) {
   convertedString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!
}

print("PrettyJsonStringFormat     ", convertedString )

let url = NSURL(string: getMenuURL)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.setValue(convertedString, forHTTPHeaderField: "SessionInfo")

print("\nPrettyHeader__    ", request.allHTTPHeaderFields)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
PrettyJsonStringFormat      {
  "Token" : "70E277954143414A",
  "UICulture" : "en-CA ",
  "LanguageCode" : "ENG",
  "CompanyID" : "QAP",
  "IMEINo" : "1jzBG3TSrMzj\/tKihlEv8g=="
}

PrettyHeader__    [:]
```

If I go with Attempt 1, `BackSlash \` is appending in that value. To avoid that I go with Attempt 2, `[Pretty Printed]` .

I don't know why `request.allHTTPHeaderFields` not having that added header values.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Why `prettyPrinted`? The server doesn't care about legibility.

Comment: In my previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582434/swift-how-to-add-dictionary-format-in-forhttpheaderfield-in-get-request in Postman screenshot, I have given value for **SessionInfo** key in **JSON** format. I have tried same in **forHTTPHeaderField** in Swift. It accepts only in String format. So , I have converted to String and then pass value in **forHTTPHeaderField**. I got error in response. Now  I am trying to print **allHTTPHeaderFields** , printed string contains, "\" . I thought this "\" may be an issue. So I go for **prettyprinted** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `convertedString` in `Attempt2` has multiple line.

[RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) says header field value having multiple lines are deprecated.

> Historically, HTTP header field values could be extended over
> multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one space
> or horizontal tab (obs-fold).  This specification deprecates such
> line folding except within the message/http media type
> (Section 8.3.1).  A sender MUST NOT generate a message that includes
> line folding (i.e., that has any field-value that contains a match to
> the obs-fold rule) unless the message is intended for packaging
> within the message/http media type.

And, `setValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)` seems to ignore such values.

```swift
// This does nothing. Just ignoring the value "A\nB"
request.setValue("A\nB", forHTTPHeaderField: "C")
```

In addition, backslash in `Attempt1` will have no problem. The server that receives the request will handle the value properly.

Comment: Thanks @pompopo , Can u help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582434/swift-how-to-add-dictionary-format-in-forhttpheaderfield-in-get-request

Comment: Is that question still not solved? You seem to have a valid String value already.

Comment: If I am having valid Converted String, then I could able get some value in **data** , From previous question.

Comment: My Query: I am hitting **GET api**, with headers, and response as Image. **Postman** screenshot I have attached in previous question. But, via **Swift**, I couldn't achieve this.  Can guide me??

Comment: Problem Facing: In **Postman** , I can able to add header in **JSON format**. But, in **Swift** , I couldn't do this. So I am trying to convert, that **JSON format** to String. Though I converted to String, api result is **Error**

Comment: Is the api server under your control? If so, you can review the difference of the requests, postman and Swift.

Comment: So sad.. v don't have that control.

Comment: What error are you getting now? Is it an api error? Show your current `allHTTPHeaderFields` . If it has valid values, there may be another problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should Check this answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324422/3806350)

Your understanding of the standard is correct. In the past, multi-line header values were supported under [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). This feature was known as "Line Folding":

> HTTP/1.1 header field values can be folded onto multiple lines if the continuation line begins with space or horizontal tab. All linear white space, including folding, has the same semantics as SP. A recipient MAY replace any linear white space with a single SP before interpreting the field value or forwarding the message downstream.